# JxBrowser web page to java swing panel drag'n drop

Tags: java, swing, javafx, drag-and-drop, jxbrowser

I would like to perform a **drag'n drop** from a webpage opened in a **javafx JxBrowser** to a **java swing panel** and transfering data between the two components. All of these components are embedded in a Java swing application. The javafx JxBrowser part has been built with a JFXPanel in Swing.

Java Swing has its own way to manage transfer data during drag'n drop... so how to begin from a javascript drag in the JxBrowser webpage to a drop in the java Swing panel ?
Have you ever experienced something like this ?